# does the $\zeta_K$ function of a function field determine the genus of that function field?

Tags: algebraic-curves, zeta-functions, function-fields

Let $K_1$ and $K_2$ both be function fields over a finite field (or algebraic curves, if you like) with zeta functions $\zeta_{K_1}$ and $\zeta_{K_2}$.  Say that $\zeta_{K_1} = \zeta_{K_2}$ - so that we have arithmetic equivalence.  Does this imply that $K_1$ and $K_2$ have the same genus as well?

The strongest relationship I know between genus and the zeta function is a theorem from Rosen's book on function fields in number theory:  if $K$ is a global function field over a finite field of genus $g$, then there is a polynomial $L_K \in \mathbb{Z}[u]$ of degree $2g$ such that

$$ \zeta_K (s) = \frac{L_K(q^{-s})}{(1-q^{-s})(1-q^{1-s})}$$

Is there a stronger relationship?  Is the genus completely determined ?

Comment: Clearly if the zeta functions are the same, then the polynomials $L_K(q^{-s})$ are the same. In particular, they have the same degree, which is twice the genus. So they have the same genus.

Comment: yes, of course.  I don't know I didn't say that despite taking the time to write it out!